# SKSpriteNode passing through SKShapeNode with multiple paths and high speed in Swift SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skshapenode

I have a game in Spritekit, the car is a `SKSpriteNode`, the line is `SKShapeNode`.

As you can see from the first gif, when I draw an X at the top so that the car falls with low speed, it works fine, but then drawing an X lower (2nd gif) so the car has more speed, it will cause the car to pass through the lines and behave erratically.

My understanding is this is the result of not meeting the collision threshold, the car is traveling faster than the systems ability to catch it.

What are my options here, I tried adding `usesPreciseCollisionDetection`, but that didn't help. Neither did adjusting the speed on the carNode nor setting the view `preferredFramesPerSecond` to 90.

What do I need to add to get proper collision when my node is traveling fast?

[image]

[image]

```
var carNode: SKSpriteNode!
var lineNode: SKShapeNode?


 override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    ...
    carNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: carTexture, size: carSize)
    carNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: carNode.size)
    carNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 1
    carNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 2
    carNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 2

    carNode.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0.5
    ...    
    addChild(carNode)
    ...
}

...

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    ...
        let newLine = SKShapeNode() 
        ...
        addChild(newLine)
        lineNode = newLine

        updateLine(to: touchLocation!)
}
...


func updateLine(to position: CGPoint) {
        let physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeChainFrom: line.path!)
        physicsBody.categoryBitMask = 2
        physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 1
        physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = 2

        line.physicsBody = physicsBody
   ...
}
```

Comment: These "X"s shown in the gif are made by touching one finger, then touching a second finger. I was unable to replicate this effect by dragging my finger across the screen, I suspect when I do the two finger touch method it is not mapping points the same way which is causing it to capture the falling call less effectively. I just disabled the multi touch, the intention of the game was to have the player draw the line anyways